# How to use remote node_modules (inside container) on WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, docker, webstorm

I installed all npm dependencies inside to the container. So I don't want to install dependencies to my host machine. Everything is okay, it works. But there is a problem with Webstorm.

It says "Unresolved function" for npm dependencies. 
How to fix that problem? How can I say "Hey webstorm, node_modules directory is inside the container :)"

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm expects `node_modules` to be located in the project folder.

You can try setting up `NODE_PATH` in **Node.js** run configuration template: **Run | Edit Configurations...**, expand **Templates** node, select **Node.js** configuration, specify `NODE_PATH` in **Environment variables** field

Please see comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19476.

But I'm not sure it will work for modules installed in container...

Answer (score 1):

Even though you expose the container's `node_modules` folder it's likely to not work as expected because `npm` dependencies are built according their host environment, which will not be the same as your local dev machine.

This statement applies even stronger if you want to run some CLI developments tools 
 - which sometimes are compiled binary files.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

Trick is to update the path inside docker container from `/your-path` to `/opt/project`.

**Detail solution**

The issue with webstorm is they don't allow you to define the path from where you can pick `node_modules`. But they have a default path from which they pick it. I was facing the same issue while I wanted to integrate remote debugging for a backend node service running inside docker.

You need to update your docker file. Suppose you were using Dockerfile was something like this

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:12.11-buster

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app

RUN npm install
```

Now this won't be detecting the node_modules for remote debugging or any other integration you need in webstorm.

But if you update the dockerfile to something like this

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:12.11-buster

# set working directory
# This done particularly for enabling debugging in webstorm.
WORKDIR /opt/project

COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json ./.npmrc /opt/project

RUN npm install
```

Then the webstorm is able to detect everything as expected.

Trick is to update the path from `/your-path` to `/opt/project`

And your docker-compose file should look something like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  backend-service:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.local
      context: ./
    command: nodemon app.js
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/project
      - /opt/project/node_modules/
    ports:
      - 6060:6060
```

You can check more details around this in [this blog](https://thetldr.tech/how-to-configure-webstorm-for-docker-container-node_modules/)